# How to use Anime4K witih MPV

Tags: mpv

How to user [Anime4K](https://github.com/bloc97/Anime4K) with MPV

I added the `mpv.conf` file with

```
profile=gpu-hq
fullscreen=yes
scale=ewa_lanczossharp
cscale=ewa_lanczossharp
video-sync=display-resample
interpolation
glsl-shaders-append="%AppData%/mpv/Shaders/Anime4K_Upscale_CNN_UL_x2.glsl"
tscale=oversample
volume-max=200
dither-depth=auto
dither=fruit
error-diffusion=sierra-lite
```

However, the problem is that when I press `Shift + I` then `2` the user shader does not show as opposed to guides available online. What could be missing in the configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying the shaders to `%AppData%\mpv` is fine, but using `%AppData%/mpv` in `mpv.conf` doesn't appear to work (tested with the [shinchiro builds](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mpv-player-windows/files/) of mpv 0.32 for Windows).

Instead, you should try using `~~/`as recommended in the [mpv manual](https://mpv.io/manual/stable/) under the *Paths* section. So, assuming your shader was located in ex.:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\mpv\Shaders\Anime4K_Upscale_CNN_UL_x2.glsl
```

You would likely want to use:

```
glsl-shaders-append="~~/Shaders/Anime4K_Upscale_CNN_UL_x2.glsl"
```