# Mpv shaders won't work?

Tags: mpv

Can someone explain where I did wrong?

I did follow the anime4k instruction but shaders wont show up? did try shift + I and then 2 and it didn't work?

this is how mine `mpv.conf` is setup:

```
profile=gpu-hq
autofit=50%
deband=no
autofit=50%
hwdec=auto-copy
screenshot-format=png
screenshot-high-bit-depth=yes
screenshot-png-compression=7
volume=100
volume-max=200

glsl-shader="C:\Users\aydin\AppData\Roaming\mpv\shaders\Anime4K_Denoise_Bilateral_Mode.glsl"
glsl-shader="C:\Users\aydin\AppData\Roaming\mpv\shaders\Anime4K_Deblur_DoG.glsl"
glsl-shader="C:\Users\aydin\AppData\Roaming\mpv\shaders\Anime4K_DarkLines_HQ.glsl"
glsl-shader="C:\Users\aydin\AppData\Roaming\mpv\shaders\Anime4K_ThinLines_HQ.glsl"
glsl-shader="C:\Users\aydin\AppData\Roaming\mpv\shaders\Anime4K_Upscale_CNN_M_x2_Deblur.glsl"
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone explain what I've done wrong?

If I am not mistaken, you may be using an incorrect command to load the shaders.

Based on a [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/1568322/how-to-use-anime4k-witih-mpv/1568472#1568472), try using`glsl-shaders-append` rather than `opengl-shader` (which doesn't seem to appear in the [up-to-date official manual](https://mpv.io/manual/master/) for mpv).

Comment: I did try like this but it still didn't work? 

glsl-shaders-append="C:\Users\aydin\AppData\Roaming\mpv\shaders\Anime4K_Denoise_Bilateral_Mode.glsl"
glsl-shaders-append="C:\Users\aydin\AppData\Roaming\mpv\shaders\Anime4K_Deblur_DoG.glsl"
glsl-shaders-append="C:\Users\aydin\AppData\Roaming\mpv\shaders\Anime4K_DarkLines_HQ.glsl"
glsl-shaders-append="C:\Users\aydin\AppData\Roaming\mpv\shaders\Anime4K_ThinLines_HQ.glsl"
glsl-shaders-append="C:\Users\aydin\AppData\Roaming\mpv\shaders\Anime4K_Upscale_CNN_M_x2_Deblur.glsl"